# Prevent form data from being cached, and re-accessing with back button

Tags: forms, caching

I am considering making a very simple form for clients to use in a sort of web browser kiosk fashion, where they submit some of their information through the computer in the lobby at their option instead of writing something out by hand. This would be used if they come in person rather than calling or going to the web site first. I already have a form on our site for clients to use from their home computers so this would be very similar but tailored for and only used for the in-person clients.

Since the form will sort of just loop back to itself (not really "back" but just have a link to go back to a fresh form) for a fresh form after every client, how can I ensure that one can't hit back a few times to see the previous client's info? It's not really sensitive data, I just would like to provide that bit of privacy. Of course clients using our web site and the form there from their own computer are responsible for their own privacy.

Apart from having customer service walk to the computer and close and reopen the browser, or using AJAX, what should I do?

The other topics I've read related to this all have someone basically saying "you're not supposed to do that, you bad person". This seems like a valid reason to me. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable autocomplete by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the input tags or form tag.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately in Firefox. I was able to hit back just fine and all the data was still in the form.

Comment: It worked! woohoo. Thank you. I can't believe that was the solution and I couldn't find it anywhere.